# Can't decode UTF8 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, utf-8

I getting XML feeds from online feeder each 3/10/60 minutes.

I parse that feeds using SimpleXML

And finnaly i store it to database and get from db on html.

Now i am sure that problem is not in database and inside feed, because same table accepts UTF8 characters when i try it manually

```
CALL myProc('čćžš')
```

Same procedure i am using when i parse xml from feed and store to database.

And feeds has normally UTF8 chars.

So i think that problem is in php, when i parse file

```
public function parseFile($path){
        $xml = '';
        $dec_file = '';
        if(!is_null($path)){
            $opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);

            $file = file_get_contents($path,false,$context);
            //$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
            if(!is_null($file)){
                $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
            }
            else{
                echo 'there is no file';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo 'Wrong path!';
        }
        return $xml;
    }
```

$xml here is not in UTF8.

I tried to do this:

```
    private function toUTF8($data){
    $utf8 = utf8_encode($data);
    return $utf8;
}
```

also instead utf8_encode i used :
**mb_convert** and **iconv**, everything i found on google i use, but no success...

I am using PDO, there is also attribute utf8, also i tried set names even is  set names already defined inside database.

```
$this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "charset='UTF-8'");
```

Each column for varchar has `utf8` collate.
I am almost sure that problem is not inside database because same table accepts čćšž. 
so i please you to think what can be problem inside PHP first.

Also there is

```
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
```

Table fixtures:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jcjdkdtaur`.`fixtures` (
  `Id` INT(32) NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` time NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `League` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeagueID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SportID` tinyint DEFAULT 1,
  `SportName` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'football',
  `Cup` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EventName` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeTeam` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeTeam_Id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AwayTeam` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AwayTeam_Id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`HomeTeam_Id`,`AwayTeam_Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

I have no idea anymore what to do...

Comment: Can you verify the data in the database itself? Does it contain correct values?

Comment: Everything is correct just utf8 varchars are not:
There is values as:
Brazil: SÃƒÂ©rie D

Comment: What mysql client do you use?

Comment: I MySQL 5.5 and 5.5 php. I am using it on Cloudways server

Comment: also on server is selected utf8 encode

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the data `SÃƒÂ©rie` from the database

Comment: What u mean for retrieving?
when i select it from database it is same, when i add mb_convert_encoding on view side then works.
But when use same mb_conver_encoding in xmltodb class than is SÃƒÂ©rie.

Comment: SOLVED !!! if(!headers_sent()){
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
} and utf8_decode is correct.

Comment: I'd imagine it was something like that. Most PHP functions that deal with strings do it with UTF-8 encoding by default. So yeah, it was just your browser not showing UTF-8 properly because there was nothing indicating it that UTF-8 was the encoding in use. Also, always make sure your script file is encoded in UTF-8 aswell, this is specially important if you are working with a foreign language with graphic accents and such.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use utf8_encode, mb_convert, or iconv or mb_convert_encoding.

Since

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY(
    CONVERT('SÃƒÂ©rie' USING latin1))
         USING utf8) USING latin1)) USING utf8)
--> 'Série'
```

I conclude that you have "double encoding".  Here's what probably happened.

- The client had characters encoded as utf8 (good); and
- `SET NAMES latin1` lied by claiming that the client had latin1 encoding; and
- The column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (good).

It seems like this should have handled the `SET NAMES`

```
$this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "charset='UTF-8'");
```

When was that done?  Before connecting?  After?  Commonly it id done during the connect:

```
PDO: $db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd);
```